# Expand grid view item on click in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I am trying to expand a grid view item on the click, basically when I click on an item in the grid view (2 column grid view) I want to expand that item to match the screen size (shown in the images below).
[image]

So as you can see in this image we just have the basic 2 column grid view, when clicking on the item I want to move all the other items around it out the way and then expand the selected item to the following:

[image]

Does anyone know how this is done? Or has anyone done this before?

Cheers

Comment: Im adding a fragment on top to visually do what you asking for. (But of course not rearranging gridview).

Comment: I would suggest you to take an imageview and gridview. Whenever user clicks on item resize gridview and enable imageview with that image.

Comment: Bro have you found any solution

Comment: @Phil Andrews : Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Beena I am afraid I was unable to find a solution that worked